# Is there a way to have Jenkins only build the PR and not the corresponding branch but also not delete the branch job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

These are the only options I have with the bitbucket plugin:
[image]

I want "exclude branches that are also filed as PRs", but when I select that jenkins actually *removes* the branch. I want to keep both the branch job and the PR job but only build the PR job. So I want the PR job to be built on commit, but also make it possible to manually run the branch job.

Is this possible without me having to add logic into my pipelines?

Comment: I looked over the plugin but it doesn't seem to have a feature like that. But why would you need this?

Answer (score 0):

We have this, with "Discover branches" on "All branches" but "Automatic branch project triggering" > "Branch names to build automatically" on "PR-\d+".

Comment: This would only build PRs automatically. I want branches to build automatically on commit to remote UNTIL a PR is opened and then only build the PR on commit to remote. I want the same behavior as "exclude branches that are also filed as PRs" I just don't want jenkins to remove the branch job.